# $4$ points in order $A,B,C,D$ lie on a circle with the extension of $AB$ meeting the extension of $DC$ at $E$ and that of $AD$ and $BC$ at $F$.

Tags: geometry, triangles, problem-solving, power-of-the-point

> $4$ points in order $A,B,C,D$ lie on a circle with the extension of $AB$ meeting the extension of $DC$ at $E$ and that of $AD$ and $BC$ at $F$. Let $EP$ and $FQ$ be tangents to this circle with points of tangency $P$ and $Q$ respectively. Suppose $EP = 60$,$FQ = 63$. Find $EF$.

**What I Tried**: Here's a picture :-
[image]

Used Power of a Point to get :-
$$EA * EB = ED * EC = 3600$$
$$FA * FD = FB * FC = 3969$$
Yet this does not help to proceed and neither finds the value of $EF$ .

I thought of Pythagoras Theorem once. Join OP and OQ and let them be $x$ each . Then we can find $OE$ and $OF$ in terms of $x$ . Not sure if that helps in the problem though.

Can anyone help me? Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I showed in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3861028/proving-pq2-is-the-sum-of-the-powers-of-p-and-q-with-respect-to-a-circl/3861050#3861050), given a circle $\Gamma$ and two points $X,Y$ such that $Y$ lies on the polar of $X$ w.r.t. $\Gamma$, we have

> $$XY^2=\text{Pow}_{\Gamma}(X)+\text{Pow}_{\Gamma}(Y)$$

Back to your case, it is well-known that $E$ lies on the polar of $F$ w.r.t. the circumcircle of $ABCD$ (recall, for example, how to [prove Brokard's Theorem](https://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=334&lmm=0)) and, hence, $$EF^2=60^2+63^2=7569\iff EF=87$$

Comment: I got your answer, I learnt something new too. Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

Hatton's [*Projective Geometry*, pg 156](https://archive.org/details/cu31924060184045/page/n171/mode/2up) gives two versions of a theorem:

> [T]he square of the distance between a pair of conjugate points with
> respect to a circle is equal to the sum of the powers of the points.

and

> If a quadrangle be inscribed in a circle, the square of the distance
> between two of its diagonal points external to the circle equals the
> sum of the square of the tangents from these points.

The second version uses your setup.

Here's a screen capture of the theorems and their proofs.

[image]

The proofs should be easy to follow, except for perhaps the last sentence.  A more explicit version would be

$$ 
\begin{align}
EF^2 &= (EK+KF)^2 \\
     &= EK^2+2EK\cdot FK+FK^2 \\
     &= EK(EK+KF)+(EK+FK)FK \\
     &= EK\cdot EF + EF\cdot FK \\
     &= EC\cdot ED + FB\cdot FC \text{ (using powers of $E,F$ wrt circles $CDF,BCE$)}\\
     &= \text{sum of powers of $E$ and  $F$ wrt original circle $ABCD$} 
\end{align}
$$